# How to check string matches format "printf like - %d/..."

Tags: c, string, stdio

I have dynamic string like: `"/users/5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh"` and also dynamic format like `"/users/%u/%d/%s"`, how to check these strings matches?

As string i mean `char[255]` or `char* str = malloc(x)`.

I tried use `sscanf` but **i dont know number of arguments and types**, if i do:

```
int res = sscanf(input, format);
```

I have stack overflow, or can i allocate stack to prevent this?
Example like this:

```
void* buffer = malloc(1024);
int res = sscanf(input, format, buffer);
```

I would like have function like this:

```
bool stringMatches(const char* format, const char* input);

stringMatches("/users/%u/%d/%s", "/users/5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh"); //true
stringMatches("/users/%u/%d/%s", "/users/5/10"); //false
stringMatches("/users/%u/%d/%s", "/users/-10/10/aaa"); //false %u is unsigned
```

Do you see any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use regex, or parse the string by yourself, If I had to do it, I would first check the number of slash '/' then read everything in between. The content between the slash must be not empty.

Comment: sscanf returns the count of parsed chars.  You compare that count with length(input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a `scanf`-like matching function in the standard lib, so you will have to write your own. Replicating all details of the `scanf` behaviour is difficult, but it's probably not necessary.

If you allow only `%` and a limited selection of single format identifiers without size, width and precision information, the code isn't terribly complex:

```
bool stringMatches(const char *format, const char *input)
{
    while (*format) {
        if (*format == '%') {
            format++;

            switch(*format++) {
            case '%': {
                    if (*input++ != '%') return false;
                }
                break;

            case 'u': 
                    if (*input == '-') return false;
                    // continue with 'd' case

            case 'd': {                
                    char *end;

                    strtol(input, &end, 0);
                    if (end == input) return false;
                    input = end;
                }
                break;

            case 's':  {
                    if (isspace((uint8_t) *input)) return false;

                    while (*input && !isspace((uint8_t) *input)) input++;
                }
                break;

            default: 
                    return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (*format++ != *input++) return false;
        }
    }

    return (*input == '\0');
}
```

Some notes:

- I've parsed the numbers with `strtol`. If you want to include floating-point number formats, you could use `strtod` for that, if your embedded system provides it. (You could also parse stretches of `isdigit()` chars as valid numbers.)
- The `'u'` case falls through to the `'d'` case here. The function `strtoul` parses an unsigned long, but it allows a minus sign, so that case is caught explicitly. (But the way it is caught, it won't allow leading white space.)
- You could implement your own formats or re-interpret existing ones. For example you could decide that you don't want leading white space for numbers or that a string ends with a slash.

Comment: `if (isspace((uint8_t) *input)) return false;` in `case 's'` not needed with comparing "printf like".

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather tricky one. I don't think C has very useful built in functions that will help you.

What you could do is using a regex. Something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    regex_t regex;

    if (regcomp(&regex, "/users/[[:digit:]]+", 0)) {
        fprintf("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *mystring = "/users/5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh";

    if( regexec(&regex, myString, 0, NULL, 0) == 0)
        printf("Match\n");
}
```

The regex in the code above does not suit your example. I just used something to show the idea. I think it would correspond to the format string `"/users/%u"` but I'm not sure. Nevertheless, I think this is one of the easiest ways to tackle this problem.

Comment: Good idea, but i need solution working in embedded (stm32 f4), library `regex.h` is speed enought?

Comment: I cannot answer if it's quick enough for you. You will have to try that for yourself. If it's not, then post a new question.

Comment: Ok, i will check this evening and will answer you :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to just try parsing it with `sscanf`, and see if the scan succeeded.

```
char * str = "/users/5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh";

unsigned int tmp_u;
int tmp_d;
char tmp_s[256];

int n = sscanf (str, "/users/%u/%d/%s", &tmp_u, &tmp_d, tmp_s);

if (n!=3)
{
   /* Match failed */
}
```

Just remember that you don't have to mach everything in one go. You can use the `%n` format specifier to get the number of bytes parsed, and increment the string for the next parse.

This example abuses the fact that `bytes_parsed` will not be modified if the parsing doesn't reach the `%n` specifier:

```
char * str = "/users/5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh";
int bytes_parsed = 0;

/* parse prefix */ 
sscanf("/users/%n", &bytes_parsed);
if (bytes_parsed == 0)
{
  /* Parse error */
}
str += bytes_parsed; /* str = "5/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh"; */

bytes_parsed = 0;

/* Parse next num */
unsigned int tmp_u
sscanf(str, "%u%n", &tmp_u, &bytes_parsed);
if (bytes_parsed)
{
  /* Number was an unsigned, do something */
}
else 
{
  /* First number was not an `unsigned`, so we try parsing it as signed */
  unsigned int tmp_d
  sscanf(str, "%d%n", &tmp_d, &bytes_parsed);
  if (bytes_parsed)
    {
       /* Number was an unsigned, do something */
    }
}
if (!bytes_parsed)
{
   /* failed parsing number */
}

str += bytes_parsed; /* str = "/10/fnvfnvdjvndfvjvdklchsh"; */

......
```

Comment: `sscanf (str, "/users/%u/%d/%s", &tmp_u, &tmp_d, tmp_s);` This is not possible as i said: i dont know number of arguments, format comes outside.

Comment: So your format string is not given at compile time? Then you should parse the format string yourself, and walk through your input string using `sscanf(s, "%u%n", ...)` , `sscanf(s, "%d%n",...)` etc, depending on the specifier in the original format string.